# I am encountering an error while attempting to retrieve domain policies and organizational units (OUs) within the domain

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I am encountering an error while attempting to retrieve domain policies and organizational units (OUs) within the domain.

script:

[image: img1]

```
    Import-Module GroupPolicy
    $forest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
    $domains = $forest.Domains|ForEach-Object { $_.Name }
    
    
    foreach ($domain in $domains) {
        Write-Host "Domain Name: $domain"
        # Connect to the domain
        $gpmc = New-Object -ComObject "GPMgmt.GPM"
        $gpmcDomain = $gpmc.GetDomain($domain)
        $gpos = $gpmcDomain.GetGPOs("All")
            foreach ($gpo in $gpos) {
                Write-Host "  GPO Name: $($gpo.DisplayName)"
                }
            
            foreach ($ou in $ous) {
                Write-Host "  OU Name: $($ou.Name)"
            }
    
    }
```

error:

[image: img2]

This is the error Iam getting.

```
    PS C:\Users\subhavignesh> C:\testing_gpo.ps1
    Domain Name: ngmgmt.internal
    Cannot find an overload for "GetDomain" and the argument count: "1"
    At C:\testing_gpo.ps1:10 char:5
    +     $gpmcDomain = $gpmc.GetDomain($domain)
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
     
    You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    At C:\testing_gpo.ps1:11 char:5
    +     $gpos = $gpmcDomain.GetGPOs("All")
    +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

1)I need to know how to connect with GPO
2)I need an output of my OU's and gpo policies under my domain

Comment: Please format your question better.

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means the method GetDomain() exists, however it does not accept only one parameter. This is noted by the statement:

```
Cannot find an overload for "GetDomain" and the argument count: "1" At C:\testing_gpo.ps1:10 char:5
```

When we check the documentation, we see that the method requires three parameters
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gpmgmt/nf-gpmgmt-igpm-getdomain

In this specific case, this function requires three parameters always. When we want to only pass the domain as a parameter, we must pass the other two parameters as an empty string.

```
$gpmc.GetDomain($domain, '', '')
```

By the way when using the autocomplete function in Powershell (Control + Space), it will also tell you what methods require which parameters.

[image]